# How to implement @DependsOnProperty(String property) in Spring(not spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using native spring (not spring boot) and I need the annotation @DependsOnProperty which is exist in spring boot.

Is it possible to implement it in spring(without adding spring-boot dependency)? If yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must mean `@ConditionalOnProperty`!? .."easy peasy": Just re-implement/copy/adopt the relevant portions of [this (spring-boot) package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition) ..

Comment: Hi @xerx593 
yes i meant ConditionalOnProperty.
And yes I tried it and it did not work, since this annotation work differently in spring boot. spring boot adds all the property file in the server environment (by default it is tomcat). and i dont want to do it this way